# How to Force the user to answer a question for open the app in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter application and I want to add a page that appears when opening the application asking the user to answer a question such as how many countries in the world - the answer is already stored in the application, so that if the answer is correct, the answer is stored and the application opens and this page does not appear again,
But if the answer is wrong, the user remains On this page, he cannot open the application until he writes the correct answer
Any suggestions or examples that would be helpful?

**Update:** I have created the following verification page that checks if the entered text is equal to the stored text,I used [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) to store the text if it is true Now iwant to know  how i can add the [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to my code?

```
class check extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _checkState createState() => _checkState();
}

class _checkState extends State<check> {

  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final verifierController = TextEditingController();
  String storedvalue = '200';
 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
  }

  Future init() async {
    final realcode = await UserSecureStorage.getCodestored() ?? '';

    setState(() {
      this.verifierController.text = realcode;
    });
  }

  Codecheck() async {
    await UserSecureStorage.setUsername(verifierController.text);

    if (storedvalue == verifierController.text) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homeScreen');
    }
    else  {
    
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/checkScreen');
    }

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Center(
              child: Stack(
            children: [
           Align(
                  child: Text(
                    'how many countries are there in the world?',
            .........
                ),
                Align(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      .......
                      controller: verifierController,
                    
                    )),
                Align(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                     .........
                        onPressed: () async {
                            Codecheck();
                          },
                       ..........
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a very simple way, you can use the [SharedPreferences](http://shared_preference) plugin to store the answer to your question permanently, for example

You can store a "**question**" key that will have the value "**how many countries are there in the world?**" (optional).
You also store an "**answer**" key with the value "**324**" (the exact number of countries in the world)

Then you create an "**answer_found**" key which will be a boolean and will update if yes or no the user answers the question correctly.

Then when the application starts, you will first query the "**answer_found**" key to see if its value is **True**.

If this value is **True**, you do not display the questionnaire page, if it is false or null, you display the questionnaire page.

When the user will enter the answer, simply compare there his answer to the one contained in the "**answer**" key in the preferences. If it is correct, simply update the key "**answer_found**" to become true. In the opposite case do nothing (or what you want)

**UPDATE :**
As you asked, here is an extract of the code.
I made it as simple as possible (although it is a bit barbaric) so that you can understand the mechanism as well as possible and that you can adapt it as you want.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((preferences) async {
    //Optional key (and can put want you want)
    //Store the question in preferences
    await preferences.setString('question', 'how many countries are there in the world?');

    //Store the answer
    await preferences.setInt('answer', 324);
  });

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool? questionAnswered;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getQuestionState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: home,
    );
  }

  Widget get home {
    if (questionAnswered == null) {
      return const Scaffold(body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
    } else if (questionAnswered!) {
      return const HomePage();
    } else {
      return const QuestionPage();
    }
  }

  Future<void> _getQuestionState() async {
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    //obtaining the present value of 'answer_found' to know if the question has been answered (with a correct answer)
    final isQuestionAnswered = preferences.getBool('answer_found') ??
        false; //if the value is null, we set it to false (to avoid a NullException)

    setState(() => questionAnswered = isQuestionAnswered);
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Home Page'),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text('WELCOME'),
        ),
      );
}

class QuestionPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuestionPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<QuestionPage> createState() => _QuestionPageState();
}

class _QuestionPageState extends State<QuestionPage> {
  late final TextEditingController _answerTextController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _answerTextController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            const Text('how many countries are there in the world?'),
            TextField(
              controller: _answerTextController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter answer'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  //Convert the user's response to be in an integer type (because we want to make a comparison with an integer)
                  //The user's response will be null, if the user has not entered an integer
                  final userAnswer = int.tryParse(_answerTextController.text);

                  if (userAnswer != null) {
                    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

                    final storedAnswer = preferences.getInt('answer')!;

                    if (userAnswer == storedAnswer) {
                      preferences.setBool('answer_found', true);

                      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage()));
                    } else {
                      //Notify user that his answer was wrong or do some stuff (what you want)
                    }
                  } else {
                    //Do some stuff
                  }
                },
                child: const Text('Validate')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have never used the flutter_secure_storage plugin, but following the code snippet I made for you, I think you could readapt it to work with flutter_secure storage, the reasoning and logic is the same.

P.S: You don't have to use shared_preferences and flutter_secure_storage at the same time. You can simply use flutter_secure_storage which, unlike shared_preferences, offers you a secure storage space (as its name indicates) and you only have to implement the same logic.

Comment: thank you very much, can you provide me some code!

Comment: I have updated my Question.

Comment: Sure... I've updated my Answer

Comment: Thank you very much again for your great answer, please I have one last question if possible, if I want to replace the previous question -'how many countries are there in the world?-by  another question like  what is your phone brands?  the answer is extracted in advance using the plugin [device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info) , knowing that I tried and did not get any result

Comment: From the start of the application you can retrieve information about the phone, save the phone brand either in the preferences or temporarily in a variable. Then you compare with the answer provided by the user.

Answer (score 1):

you would check the user's answer, if it's correct, you save a boolean in the [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) and then navigate to the app home page and every time you open the app you check on this boolean from the shared preferences, if it's true then don't show the question and open the home page directly, if not, then show the question again

Answer (score -1):

I hope you will have the splash screen as the first screen to load in your application.

now, when the first screen will load.
make this first screen a stateful.

this will allow you to use the "initstate" method. and you know that the initstate method will be called first to execute the code.

```dart
initstate(){
 /// in this case I am using "get_storage" to store the data in local.
 GetStorage prefs = GetStorage("ApplicationName");
 bool isAnswered = prefs.read("isAnsweredQuestion") ?? false;
 if(isAnswered){
  /// redirect to the other screen.
 }else{
  /// redirect to the screen where you have the questions
  /// or open the dialog having questions.
 }
 super.initstate();
};
```

the initstate method will execute for the first time when the application loads and execute the splash screen and it will check for the local data store.

if the user is opening the application for the first time then the local data will be null and we have used the null-check operator to handle that.

If the user already answered the question then we will get "true" stored in the local. and we will redirect the user to the other screen in that case.